# Edit, Page History, and Incoming Links on Wiki Page

Tags: 2013, wiki-pages

I have two SharePoint 2013 site collections, each with a Site Pages library. One of them shows links at the top of each Site Page, like this:

```
Edit | Page History | Incoming Links
```

while the other does not. I have created a new Wiki Page in both libraries, one has these links, one doesn't. I am sure there is an obvious answer, and I recall seeing this problem before, but Google has failed me so far. How do I turn off these links on my Wiki Pages?

UPDATE: Looking at the page source, these links belong to the "WikiMiniConsole" placeholder. It has a stylee of visibility:hidden, which makes me speculate these links are only visible to users with edit rights to the Site Pages library.

Comment: Can you upload some screenshots?

Comment: No, this is on a closed network. The links appear at the top of the page, directly above the content. They look just like I typed them, except there is an edit icon to the left of the Edit link.

Comment: Are you using the default master pages? these commands are usually found in the 'page' ribbon.

Comment: Yes. The Site Collection that is showing these links is brand new, and I have not customized the master page. I have tried changing the look and feel, and no change.